# SQLite Foreign Keys | Different SQ files

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqldelight

I have an Android project that includes a local database written in SQLite. There exists an sqldelight folder which contains a .sq file for every table in the database (User.sq, Routine.sq ...). I am able to access/use the tables and procedures defined here within my project.

Now, I intent to add Foreign Key relations to the database. However, if I try something like  `FOREIGN KEY (this_table_fk) REFERENCES OtherTable(other_table_pk)`, the project will not build because the .sq file I'm in is not able to find the `OtherTable` table created from the `CREATE TABLE` statement in OtherTable.sq or, by extension, its column `other_table_pk`.

How can I allow the 2 different .sq files to "see" the tables generated by the other?

I tried putting the CREATE TABLE statements of `ThisTable` and `OtherTable` in the same .sq file, but I get `mismatched input 'CREATE' expecting (<EOF>, IDENTIFIER, JAVADOC_COMMENT)` on the second CREATE TABLE statement. I'd much rather have a solution that keeps each table in its own .sq file, though.

Thanks.

Basic showing of `ThisTable.sq` and `OtherTable.sq`

ThisTable.sq:

```
CREATE TABLE ThisTable (
      this_table_pk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      name TEXT,
      location TEXT,
      start_date TEXT,
      end_date TEXT, 
      this_column_fk INTEGER,
      FOREIGN KEY (this_column_fk) REFERENCES OtherTable(other_column_pk)
```

);

OtherTable.sq:

```
CREATE TABLE OtherTable (
      other_table_pk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      name TEXT,
      location TEXT,
      start_date TEXT,
      end_date TEXT);
```

Comment: Can you post the .sq files your talking about?  It's hard to help without seeing more code.

Comment: yeah I'll edit the OP. I'm not trying to make money with what I'm making or anything but I tend to think it good principle to abstract specific implementation. One minute.

Comment: It's done, by the by.

Comment: Do you have access to the create script or code for when the DB is created?  My guess is that ThisTable is getting created before OtherTable

Comment: That was a good hypothesis and it put me on the right track. The correct answer was in a project-specific discrepancy between the names of the tables before and after generation due to a quirk in how the Android Studio platform was being used. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to a misuse of the Android Studio platform. However, parkgrrr conjectured that it was based on an ordering of table creation, which led me to the correct answer.